# VBA Microsoft Text Driver having text in the where-clause

Tags: vba, odbc

I use this function for getting info from an text-file:

```
Function Import_Kundendaten_FromText(sqlstring As String) As String
'On Error GoTo MeinEnde
Dim cn As ADODB.connection
Dim rec As ADODB.Recordset
    Set cn = New ADODB.connection
    On Error Resume Next
    cn.Open "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};" & _
        "Dbq=" & "" & ";" & "Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;"
    On Error GoTo 0
    If cn.State <> adStateOpen Then Exit Function
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rec = New ADODB.Recordset
    rec.Open LCase(sqlstring), cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
       If Not rec.BOF And Not rec.EOF Then Import_Kundendaten_FromText = rec.Fields(0).Value    '
MeinEnde:
If Err <> 0 Then fehlerverarbeitung ("Err-Nr: " & Err.Number & Chr(10) & "Err-Desc: " & Err.Description & Chr(10) & _
    "Err-Source: " & Err.Source & Chr(10) & "Sub Import_Kundendaten_FromText" & Chr(10) & Now())
End Function
```

If I use this like

```
Import_Kundendaten_FromText("SELECT SOMETEXTFIELD FROM C:\variable_outl_kunden.txt WHERE CustNo = 105")
```

=> works perfect!

```
Import_Kundendaten_FromText("SELECT SOMETEXTFIELD FROM C:\variable_outl_kunden.txt WHERE CustName = 'Someone'")
```

=> does not give any results nor an error!!!

I have no idea, why I can not use text in the where-staement - any ideas?

Thanks!
Max

Comment: Most likely CustName is not recognized as a text column. Try using a schema.ini >> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Please post the first lines of your input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a number of problems with your code.

1. As mentioned in the comments, you need a Schema.ini file for your code to work. - I assume you have got one already because otherwise your code would only work if the text file matches the default settings of the Text Driver.
2. The `On Error Resume Next` statements, particularly the second one, in your code are most likely the reason why you do not see any error message.
3. The column names **and data** in the text file will be treated case sensitive. So your `LCase(sqlstring)` is not a good idea unless the text file content is all lower case.